# Adding costum styles to Typo3 RTE. Some are not saved

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, rte

I add costum styles to the RTE with a CSS File:

```
RTE.default.contentCSS = EXT:netjapan/Resources/Public/css/rte.css
```

For some elements this works. For example for a `ul`Element:

```
ul.liststyle1 {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
```

When I select the ul in the RTE I can chose the Blockstyle `liststyle1`.

I want to do the same for `p`:

```
p.test {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

And when I select the `p` I can chose the Blockstyle `test` and the style is used. But when I save the Blockstyle is gone.

I added this Typoscript:

```
RTE.default {
    removeTags = sdfield, strike
    proc.entryHTMLparser_db.removeTags = sdfield, strike
}
```

So that `p` is not in the removeTags list. But it had no effect.

Anyone know how it comes that the Blockstyle is removed on the `p`Element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had simillar problem last week. Sometimes RTE is going crazy. I mean that there is no logical sense in it. Check this: marke the text and use the container style it will wrap it in `div` but there will be also `<p>` in it so you will have something like `<div><p class="bodytext">text</p></div>` - you can add style for that. At least this solved my problem

Comment: @nbar i didn't say it is a cool solution but it is doing the job ;)

Comment: sure! And I would not have that problem if only I had to use the RTE. But as the customer edits this, she will not be very happy with it.

Comment: Oh how sad. It does not allways do the job. I did some tests. In my first test it worked. In my second test the style is added to the `p` but it was not saved again. test1 and test2 looked really similar....